# How do I make Vim ask to download spellfiles without manually typing ":set spelllang=..."?

Tags: spell-checking

I have this in my Vim configuration file:

```
set spell
set spelllang=fr
```

When I start Vim, I get an error:

```
Warning: Cannot find word list "fr.utf-8.spl" or "fr.ascii.spl"
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Notice that Vim does not offer to download the missing spellfiles. It is only when I manually type `:set spelllang=fr`, does Vim offer to download the missing spellfile(s):

```
Cannot find spell file for "fr" in utf-8
Do you want me to try downloading it?
(Y)es, [N]o:
```

Is there a way to make Vim prompt the user to download missing spellfiles when starting Vim, instead of making it necesaary to manually type `:set spelllang=...` to make Vim ask?

(Vim version: 8.1.2269 on Ubuntu 20.04).

Comment: I wonder if this question got to HNQ due to the reading of "spellfiles" as "spellbooks" by the visitors :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, the point is `SpellFileMissing` event is captured by a plugin, but all plugins are loaded *after* your `vimrc` has been processed.

In principle, we can delay options setting until `:h VimEnter`

```
if !v:vim_did_enter
    autocmd VimEnter * ++once ++nested set spell spelllang=fr
endif
```

But, in fact, it's much cleaner and simpler only `set spelllang=fr` in your vimrc, but *not set spell*. You can switch it on later manually or per ftplugin(s) as needed.